# How to duplicate things on laptop?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I duplicate things/fireworks/heads in Minecraft 1.11 on laptop?

Comment: If you're in creative mode, middlie-clicking the item in your inventory will make a new stack of it.

Comment: If laptop does not have middle click button (touchpad?), you may find you can set a driver option to recognise both buttons together as a middle click, a multiple finger tap on the touchpad or a corner tap. This depends more on the particula touchpad and it's drivers than minecraft. The other option is you can rebind "pick block" to another key in minecraft however this doesn't help if you need middle click in other applications in the future.

Comment: Are you in survival mode or creative mode?

Answer (score -1):

You could go into your options menu, click controls, and change the mouse3 control to a key of your choosing.

Comment: I said that already though

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry, I didn't realize you had mentioned that.